# Is dataSource of UITableView exactly a delegate design pattern like the table information provider delegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview, design-patterns

A `UITableView` object has two properties: one `delegate`, and one `dataSource`.  Are they exactly the same design pattern?  I don't see books or reference calling `dataSource` a second delegate for the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same thing but they are using the delegate pattern.

They are both different and distinct delegates that serve different purposes. One property is for the UITableViewDataSource and the other is for UITableViewDelegate.

Here is how they are defined in UITableView.h:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate
```

The delegate pattern is pretty simple and the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) entry sums it up pretty well:

> In software engineering, the delegation pattern is a design pattern in
>   object-oriented programming where an object, instead of performing one
>   of its stated tasks, delegates that task to an associated helper
>   object. There is an Inversion of Responsibility in which a helper
>   object, known as a delegate, is given the responsibility to execute a
>   task for the delegator. The delegation pattern is one of the
>   fundamental abstraction patterns that underlie other software patterns
>   such as composition (also referred to as aggregation), mixins and
>   aspects.

Comment: it seemed that books or references "dare not" call `dataSource` as a "delegate", so I wondered why